# how to display current date in textbox using placeholder in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<body>
Date: <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder=" "/>
</body>
</html>
```

What should i specify inside placehoder quotes so that i can view current date in my textbox

Comment: Have you even tried researching this? That much is expected of you before posting questions here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are one of the soultions how to display current date in textbox:

**1. JAVASCRIPT SOLUTION**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">


Date: <input type="text" id="demo"/>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('demo').value= Date();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Instead of **value**, in the same way by id, you could set the `placeholder` as you wish:

```
document.getElementById('demo').placeholder= Date();
```

---

**2. JQUERY SOLUTION**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">


Date: <input type="text" id="demo"/>

<script>
function myFunction() {

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#demo').attr("placeholder", Date());
});

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks,I know if i use date function in value it gets displayed in textbox..But i Want the textbox value to disappear as soon as user clicks on texbox.datsy i preferred to use placeholer.Coz if i use value as suggested by u,wen d user clicks on textbox the date value will still be der.I just want the current date to be reflected in textbox just as a default one and to disappear as soon as user clicks on it....

Comment: I got it, I think that's the solution that you want to see. I just set the placeholder instead of value in the same way...

Comment: @arman1991 how can we change the date format inside the textbox ?? I just need dd/mm/yyyy